# Integral relating gamma function's linear subspaces

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, gamma-function

I'm trying to solve the equation:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(s\ln(t)+\frac{π(4n+1)}{4})}{\sqrt{t}e^t}\mathrm{d}t=0$$
For the variable $s\in\mathbb{R}$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is any nonzero integer.
This is related to a more complicated integral equation:
$$\int_0^\infty \left(\frac{\cos(s\ln(t))-\sin(s\ln(t))}{\sqrt{t}e^t}\right)\mathrm{d}t=0$$
This equation involves certain linear subspaces of the complete gamma function. More specifically, the subspace of all the vomplef numbers of the form: $a(1+i)$ where $a$ is any real number. Thanks for the help.

Comment: presumably for a $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and not $s(t)$?

Comment: Indeed. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Mathematica can compute both integrals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MariuszIwaniuk notes, these integrals are computable. In fact, not only by Mathematica [sic], but by human beings: replace the cosine by its expression in terms of exponentials. Grouping things gives a linear combination of two integrals of the form $\int_0^\infty t^{s-1/2}\,e^{-t}\;dt/t$, with the coefficients of the linear combination depending on $n$.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly the integral transformation i was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: did you use some method of integration or special technique to get this result?

Comment: I certainly do consistently consider re-expressing trig functions in terms of exponentials, especially when they're combined. Also, combinations of polynomials and exponentials tend to give Gamma functions, which satisfy many simplifying identities, so I'd look for those, too. :)

Comment: Thanks! Exponentials have certainly proven useful... But i'm really asking because i can't get the exact form you got. So far, the linear combination i get uses integrals of the form: $\int_0^\infty t^{is-1/2}e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t$. Also, it uses complex coefficients. Am i missing something? (Sorry if i'm nitpicky, but i have to write this down on a paper later. :'))

Comment: But you're fine: integral of power of $t$ against $e^{-t}$. Simplifies... no serious issue.